How to keep original IP of user after forwarding port 443 through iptables?
I have two servers for example with such IPs:

1serv - ip: 99.99.99.99
2serv - ip: 111.111.111.111

I need all traffic on 99.99.99.99 -> 111.111.111.111
I write:
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j DNAT --to 111.111.111.111:443
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 99.99.99.99

All works, but I see on 2serv IP of 1serv without IP of user.
Can you help me and write commands so that it works?

The 99s and 111s addresses are clearly made up. It's a little annoying because it's not possible even to see if these are public IP addresses or private ones. Is there a direct route between them? Do you really need a NAT layer at all or could you just use routing?

Do you "own" or manage both hosts? If there's no direct route would you be averse to setting up something like Wireguard to create a direct route?

Both public. It need that hide country host of serv. Servers in different countries. May be IPIP?
